# Wrap another method at class definition

Tags: python, class, properties, python-3.x, instance-methods

I want to create a method (`set`) that injects arguments into another (`set_result`). I've tried this using `partial` as below.

```
from functools import partial

class MyClass(MyClassParent):
    set = partial(MyClassParent.set_result, None)
```

But this doesn't work. When calling `set` on an instance of `MyClass` I get this error:

```
TypeError: set_result() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I assume this means the implicit `self` is not passed. If I write `set` like this it works:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwds)
    self.set = partial(self.set_result, None)
```

How can I wrap `set_result` using the former method?

Comment: What's wrong with the second version? That's the right way to do this.

Comment: What's the signature of `set_result`?

Comment: @Marcin: I just don't see why I can't bind it more succinctly, and with less overhead at "runtime". If I can do the wrapper using partial, the "wrapper" is done from C.

Comment: I don't think `self.set = partial(self.set_result, None)` is any less succinct than `set = partial(MyClassParent.set_result, None)`, and worrying about "overhead at runtime" sounds like premature optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that `functools.partial` is not a descriptor. Accessing it on an instance will not return a bound method.

There's a Python [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue4331) on the tracker for this, to which I submitted a [patch](http://bugs.python.org/file25016/functools.partial-descrget.patch).

Answer (score 0):

```
set = staticmethod(partial(MyClassParent.set_result, None))
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what OP wants. given that his second version works correctly. This will create a version of set_result that has a None self, and still needs to take an argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass(MyClassParent):
    set = partial(MyClassParent.set_result, MyClassParent, None)
```